# Jetty mysql connection-pool configuration error: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/jdbc/---(mysql 5.0+jetty 7.0.1)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jetty, connection-pooling

My configuration files

*project/WEB-INF/web.xml*:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>ConnectionPool DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mysql</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

project/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml:

```
<New id="mysql" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
<Arg>jdbc/mysql</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <Set name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</Set>
            <Set name="username">user</Set>
            <Set name="password">pwd</Set>
            <Set name="maxActive">50</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

---

### code to invoke:

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql");
con=ds.getConnection();
```

---

scripts to start jetty:

```
java -DOPTIONS=plus -jar start.jar

java -jar start.jar
```

Either way to start jetty, I got following error:

---

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/jdbc/mysql'
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:632)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:663)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:110)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

---

The questions are:

- what is the problem here?
- Any other configurations needed?
- where to put following jar files:

  - commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
  - mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar

Thank you!

Comment: "remaining name 'env" appears to suggest the entire environment is not found. is jetty-env.xml loaded at all? Perhaps you need to add it to -DOPTIONS or something?

Answer (score 10):

#### Note: The following assumes you're using Jetty 7.2.2+ (probably works with any Jetty 7.0+).

The problem is you're missing ONE extra layer of indirection. Even though you've configured Jetty in your webapp,  you *still* need to tell the Jetty container  that it needs to look for jetty-env.xml in your webapp.  To do that, add the following to your jetty.xml (under ${JETTY_INSTALL_DIR}/etc:

```
<Call name="setAttribute">
  <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.configuration</Arg>
  <Arg>
      <Array type="java.lang.String">
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
      </Array>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

NOW Jetty will know to parse the jetty-env.xml you've created.

Comment: Helped me out, was exactly what I was missing. Jetty8 too BTW. Thanks!

Comment: Well I'm very appreciative of the fact that you did answer a question that was a year old because it help me immensely, thanks you!  I am also using Jetty 8 as well.

Comment: I think you are kidding no one. I was also desperate for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

This drove me nuts all day long. FYI, I am working with Jetty 6.1.22. The comment to the first post is on track -- I had a file name jetty-env.xml in WEB-INF, and it was being ignored. I renamed it to jetty-web.xml *and* specified the full name of the data source (i.e. java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatasource) for the second argument of the New directive and it worked.

Comment: This is what I had to do too.  I am using Jetty-Hightite 7.0.1

Comment: This fix worked for me, thank you for answering an older post.  I had to add the full path name to my declaration like so: <New id="MotionDS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
     <Arg>java:comp/env/jdbc/DBName</Arg>
     <Arg>
       <New class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
         <Set name="driverClass">org.postgresql.Driver</Set>
         <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</Set>
         <Set name="username"></Set>
         <Set name="password"></Set>
         ...
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New></pre>

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem. 
My *project/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml* was:

```
<New id="DS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref id="studentsApp"/></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/DS</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students</Set>
            <Set name="User">root</Set>
            <Set name="Password">root</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

And same error was occured. I tried to switch jndi scopes - didn't work. 
Event when I've tried to look into java:comp/ to look what jndi entries available, it returns nothing. Code for jndi listing used:

```
Context t = (Context)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp");
listContext(t, "");

private static final void listContext(Context ctx, String indent) {
    try {
        NamingEnumeration list = ctx.listBindings("");
        while (list.hasMore()) {
            Binding item = (Binding) list.next();
            String className = item.getClassName();
            String name = item.getName();
            System.out.println(indent + className + " " + name);
            Object o = item.getObject();
            if (o instanceof javax.naming.Context) {
                listContext((Context) o, indent + " ");
            }
        }
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

I knew for sure that **jetty-web.xml** was loaded - I've added:

```
<Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="info"><Arg>Starting my super test application</Arg></Call>
```

on top of the **jetty-web.xml** and it outputs at the server start.

Than, I decided to move from non-portable **jetty-web.xml** to **context.xml** file, placed it into *$JETTY_HOME/contexts*, placed MySQL connector jar into *$JETTY_HOME/lib/ext* and it started to work.

Looks like Jetty have a problem with JNDI entries if they are loaded from **jetty-web.xml**.

Comment: I can't use the contexts folder like this or I would.  See Sean's comment above for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

[Jetty documentation indicates a three-step process](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JNDI#Quick_Setup) for using a JNDI resource such as a database. These instructions should apply to Jetty 7 and Jetty 8.

1. Edit the `$JETTY_HOME/start.ini` file as follows:
2. Modify the Server `OPTIONS` to include "plus", for example:

   `OPTIONS=Server,jsp,jmx,resources,websocket,ext,plus`
3. Near the bottom of the file, in the section on Configuration files, add the following line after `etc/jetty.xml`:

   `etc/jetty-plus.xml`

Comment: I had this same issue and I followed the documentation and in the end I had to use the full jndi path e.g. 'java:comp/env/jdbc/DBName' in my  <New id="DS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"> declaration.  I added mine in jetty.xml to keep it simple in the beginning.